# Maze Generator in AS3 using tiles

Tags: actionscript-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good algorithm to generate a maze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-generate-a-maze)

Long story short, I have to make a random maze generator in AS3.

I've seen plenty of tutorials on maze generation but nothing that matches the my needs.
The maze has to be made of ten tiles (they are MovieClips), that are possible states of parts of the maze (for example: just wall; just opened space; wall north, wall east; wall west; etc). I have to figure out how to generate the maze using these ten tiles.

Could someone please give me a light on how to do this? Anything I think of sounds extremely complicated, there must be an easier way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the source code of a maze generator here: [Maze on WonderFL](http://wonderfl.net/c/v7Vh)

And after you have generated a maze you could see what kind of wall you have with the relation of the other points, this shouldn't be too hard when you actually finish creating a maze.