# Algorithm to generate a maze with / without solution

Tags: algorithm, maze

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-generate-a-maze) question here on Stack Overflow about good algorithms to generate mazes. I would need an algorithm which also generates mazes but where I can decide if they have a solution or not. Which algorithm is suitable for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want it for? My first guess would be testing maze-solving algorithms - and in that case I would guess you might also be interested in having multiple solutions, loops, dead-ends, etc. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: @HansOlsson Yes, I want to test maze-solving algorithms

Comment: A good maze generating algorithm always generates a maze that has a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Recursive Backtracker to generate a labyrinth with one solution. Or any of the several [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681987/1428679) available.

These algorithms will generate some kind of labyrinth data format, usually indicating for each cell the status of two of its edges (so, two bits per cell), and also the unique solving path.

Then, if you want for it *not* to have a solution, choose a cell in the middle of the path and add one wall, killing the only solution there was. How to do this depends on the algorithm's maze data format. It could be as simple as

```
if (noSolution) {
    var kill = Math.floor(maze.path.length/2);
    maze.cell[maze.path[kill].y]
             [maze.path[kill].x].edges = { };
}
```

Comment: Can you please more specific. How can I determine which cell belongs to the path? And is there, using the recursive backtracker, only a single solution?

Comment: The determination will depend on the algorithm. Which if it generates a perfect maze, as those listed in the linked answer do, willl give you one and only one solution.